# Python - Combining For Loops

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, for-loop

I have two dictionaries of data from 2016 and 2017 respectively which have the same 5 keys. I want to calculate the percentage of each key's value to the sum of the values in its dictionary and then join the two percentages of each individual key to a label. I have managed to do so below but my method requires a lot of for looping and seems somewhat clunky. I am looking for ways of condensing or rewriting my code so as to make it more efficient.

```
UsersPerCountry, UsersPerPlatform, UsersPerPlatform2016, UsersPerPlatform2017 = Analytics.UsersPerCountryOrPlatform()

labels = []
sizes16 = []
sizes17 = []
sumc1 = 0
sumc2 = 0
percentages = []

for k, v in dict1.iteritems():
    sumv1 += v
for k, v in dict1.iteritems():
    v1 = round(((float(v) / sumc1) * 100), 1)
    percentages.append(v1)
    labels.append(k)
    sizes16.append(c)
for k, v in dict2.iteritems():
    sumv1 += v
for k, v in dict2.iteritems():
    v2 = round(((float(v) / sumc1) * 100), 1)
    percentages.append(v2)
    sizes17.append(c)
for i in range(5):
    labels[i] += (', ' + str(percentages[i]) + '%' + ', ' + str(percentages[i + 5]) + '%')
```

This is what the label looks like:

[image]

**EDIT:** I have now added the variable declaration. I thought the hashed line about setting all variables to empty lists or 0 would suffice.

Comment: Please post a complete code snippet. e.g. `sumc1` and `c` are never declared...

Comment: Have you considered using `Pandas`? You could put each dictionary into a `pd.DataFrame` and use panda's vectorized mechanisms to perform the same calculation in two lines. ie `df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)` and `df2=pd.DataFrame(dict2)`, or even combine them into a single `df = pd.concat([df1,df2], keys = [2016,2017])`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Panda's data frame class to simplify things. I am a bit unsure of how your percentages are being calculated so that may need to be worked out a bit but otherwise, try this:

```
import pandas as pd

#convert data to DataFrame class
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)

#compute the percentages
percnt1 = df1.sum(axis=0).div(df1.sum().sum())
percnt2 = df2.sum(axis=0).div(df2.sum().sum())

#to get the sum:
percnt1 + percnt2
```

Here's an example:

```
## create a data frame:
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Android':np.random.poisson(10,100), 'iPhone':np.random.poisson(10,100), 
'OSX':np.random.poisson(10,100), 'WEBGL':np.random.poisson(10,100), 'Windows':np.random.poisson(10,100)})

In [11]: df1.head()
Out[11]:
   Android  OSX  WEBGL  Windows  iPhone
0       12   12      9        9       5
1        9    8     14        7      11
2       12   10      7       10      11
3       11   12      7       17       5
4       15   16     15       11      13

In [10]: df1.sum(axis=0).div(df1.sum(axis=0).sum())
Out[10]:
Android    0.205279
OSX        0.198782
WEBGL      0.200609
Windows    0.198376
iPhone     0.196954
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Without Pandas:

You should take advantage of some of Python's built-in features, as well as functions. Here I'm trying to replicate what you're doing to be a little more Pythonic.

Note this is untested because you didn't give a full code snippet (sumc1 and c were undeclared). I wrote this based on what I think you're trying to do.

```
# Your size16/size17 lists appear to be full of the constant c
# can use Pythons list replication operation
sizes16 = [c]*len(dict1)
sizes17 = [c]*len(dict2)

# define function for clarity / reduce redundancy
def get_percentages(l):
  s = sum(l)
  percentages = [ round(((float(n) / s)*100),1) for n in l ]  # percentages calculation is a great place for list comprehension
  return percentages

# can grab the labels directly, rather than in a loop
labels = dict1.keys()

percentages1 = get_percentages(dict1.values())
percentages2 = get_percentages(dict2.values())

# no magic number 5
for i in range(len(labels)):
  labels[i] += (', ' + str(percentages[i]) + '%' + ', ' + str(percentages[i + 5]) + '%')
```

That last line could be cleaned up if I had a better idea of what you were doing.

I haven't looked closely, but this code may run over the data an extra once or twice, so it may be a little less efficient. However, it's much more readable IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to go without an external library. You don't mention any problems in the way the code runs, just it's aesthetic (which one could argue has an effect on the way it runs). Anyway, this looks clean:

```
# Sample data
d1 = {'a':1.,'b':6.,'c':10.,'d':5.}
d2 = {'q':10.,'r':60.,'s':100.,'t':50.}

# List comprehension for each dictionary sum
sum1 = sum([v for k,v in d1.items()])
sum2 = sum([v for k,v in d2.items()])

# Using maps and lambda functions to get the distributions of each dictionary
d1_dist = map(lambda x: round(x/sum1*100, 1), list(d1.values()))
d2_dist = map(lambda y: round(y/sum2*100, 1), list(d2.values()))


# Insert your part with the labels here (I really didn't get that part)

>>> print(d1_dist)
[4.5, 45.5, 27.3, 22.7]
```

And if you want to join the original keys from a dictionary to these new distribution values, just use:

```
d1_formatted = dict(zip(list(d1.keys()), d1_dist))
>>> print(d1_formatted)
{'a': 4.5, 'c': 45.5, 'b': 27.3, 'd': 22.7}
```